# How to limit the width of a subheading?

Tags: sectioning, width

The thesis formatting manual has the following requirement:

> **Subheading width:**
>
> A long subheading title should be divided into two or more lines. No
> single line may be wider than 4 inches. Subheadings may be all single-
> or all double-spaced within the thesis.

However, I have several chapters and sections with long names. I have looked into the `titlesec` package but still have no solution at this moment.

Comment: You should provide the community with what we call a (complete) [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Why? Sectional units depend heavily on the document class, and some solutions may depend on whether it's compatible with what you're using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does the 4in limit includes the numbering? Which exactly are subheadings? It looks as if chapter produce headings and lower sectional units (\section, \subsection, etc.) produce subheadings. To which usectional units should this 4in limit apply?

Comment: Could you please add a MWE example to your post, otherwise we are guessing a lot?

Comment: You can always use a    \parbox{4in}{}.

Answer (score 1):

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[DIV9]{typearea}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\ltx@subsection}{\subsection}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][]{\ltx@subsection[#1]{\protect\parbox[t]{4in}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Heading}
\subsection{Very very very very very very long subheading with no single line wider than 4 inches}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\parbox[t]` would probably look better.